# Performance difference between different GPUs

Tags: photoshop, video, performance

Background - I have two desktop PCs, the primary one has an nVidia 8800GT (512MB) video card and the other has an AMD V4800 (1GB) card. The second PC is now surplus to requirements and will be sold.
Benchmarks suggest that the V4800 is a bit better, performance-wise, than the 8800GT.
Question - Should I swap the V4800 card into the PC I am keeping? Would the V4800 give a noticeable performance increase in Photoshop and Lightroom?
I know both of these cards are old, and a more modern one would give better results but as the V4800 is available effectively for free should I swap it over to the PC I am keeping? - Would I see any significant improvement to warrant fiddling about swapping cards, getting DisplayPort adapters, etc?

Thanks,  John

Comment: If you could simply keep the V4800 so that you could benchmark it, might as well hold on to the V4800 now, figure out which one is better, and then scrap the less performant piece.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I suppose I wanted someone to say there's no significant performance gain, but sadly no-one did. :-(
More reading suggests that the V4800 supports OpenCL better, so as well as raw 'horsepower' there might be a benefit there. I'll do a couple of tests. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple answer to that because :

1. The same GPU in 2 differents systems doesn't give the same performance. It depends on a lot of things (BUS speed, to name the most obvious, thus the motherboard)
2. You need to compare the OpenCL versions supported by both GPU drivers and check if Photoshop use them. If the versions don't match, you have virtually no GPU at all.
3. The features actually using the GPU in Photoshop are not legion, in fact it's most UI-level enhancements : https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/photoshop-cc-gpu-card-faq.html

So at the end, you need to test and benchmark.